# dbt Redshift Database Error in model , operator does not exist: text || boolean

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

The first time a run an incremental model in dbt is works just fine but the second time I run it I get this error:

Database Error in model my_incremental_model(models\my_incremental_model.sql)
operator does not exist: text || boolean
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
compiled SQL at target\run\dbt\models\my_incremental_model.sql

The table has columns bigint, string, boolean, and int.  Any ideas?  Here is the model

```
{{ config(
    materialized = 'incremental',
    unique_key = "col1||col2||col3||col4",
    sort = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
) }}

select distinct 
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
from 
    {{ source("src", "some_table") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

dbt can build the composite by itself, we don't need to do it manually. You just need to replace your unique key definition by:

```
unique_key = ['col1', 'col2', "col3', 'col4']
```

the way you are creating the key manually might not be supported, it might be interesting to look at the erronous generated/compiled sql given in your error message:
*...compiled SQL at target\run\dbt\models\my_incremental_model.sql..*

Answer (score 0):

Fond a solution.  Had to cast the boolean to an integer

```
unique_key = "col1||col2||cast(col3 as integer)||col4",
```